# JSF redirect to other page with parameter

Tags: java, jsf

I'm redirecting to another page:

```
String uri = "../test/planOutput.jsf?job_id=121250";
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch(uri);
```

It works, but the URL doesn't change,
I must see the new URL with the parameter.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 6):

You aren't redirecting the request to a different target at all. You are dispatching the request to a different source. Use [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29) instead of [`ExternalContext#dispatch()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#dispatch%28java.lang.String%29).

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(uri);
```

A redirect basically instructs the webbrowser to fire a new HTTP request on the given URL. That's also why you see the URL change being reflected in webbrowser's address bar. A dispatch basically instructs the webserver to use a different source for the current request/response. Since this happens internally and does not end up in a new HTTP request, the webbrowser know nothing about the change and the address bar won't be changed.

Comment: @BalusC, sorry to barge in, but do you have any good tutorials on JSF? Do you find it wise to integrate it with Spring? If so, any good tutorials for that too?

Comment: @Rivki: you're welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer accepted if it has solved/answered the problem/question. @The Elite Gentlemen: If you start with nothing, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5312566#5312566). As to Spring, that depends. If you're using Java EE 6 and starting with nothing, I'd give the builtin APIs a chance. CDI (JSR299, Weld) is meant to supplant Spring. If you're working with existing Spring backends, I think it's not worth the effort to change it, so just stick to Spring. As to Spring-JSF integration: I have no idea. Never did it.

Comment: @The Elite: you're welcome. I would however appreciate if you just press `Ask Question` in the future, so that we can earn some points ;)